# EF Code First - How to Model This?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on a web app (MVC) utilizing Entity Framework code first and I'm trying to figure out how to model this.  I could certainly add 15 bool values to a class (bits in the database), but that seems like a pathetic way to go about it.  I currently have a customer object that will contain an object for the policies shown in the image below.

[image]

I want my view to look just like what is above and there are currently no plans to add a 6th, but architecting the model to support that possibility would be important.

```
public class customer{
   //some random properties like Id, Name, Owner, Etc.
   //I could put 15 bools here for the policies in the image
   //I could put a policy object here?
}
```

Comment: What does your class model look like now?  Specifically is "Original Medicare" a class different than "TriCare for Life", or are they two instances of the same class?

Comment: I just updated the post a bit...  Essentially the customer object is the master for all this data.  Each customer has a Medicare policy that contains answers to these questions (answers are yes/no or bools)...

Comment: The decorator pattern will be your friend here with an enum for the type and a bit mask for the values. I'm in the mountains with my phone so unfortunately can't elaborate much until later here :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a design that is simple, self describing, scalable, normalized and extensible. You can add additional policy types or patient types without recompiling the system.  You didn't state which database engine you are using, so in order to make it work across most database platforms, I'd suggest you use [TPC](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx).

[image: Diagram]

A patient is just a role that a person (aka party) plays in the system. You can have other roles such as "doctor", "employee", "policy holder" and so forth each with their own data.  It is important to note that roles are temporal, meaning a single role can be voided, while the person performs other roles in the system.

If "Existing", "AgeIn", "NewPatient" can be determined by looking at properties of the Role or Party, the there is no need for a PatientType.  I added it because it is unclear how the types of patiences are defined. You may very well just have a property on Patient to define that.

A party represents any legal entity. Parties have relationships which are often important for a business. So when "Sam" (a person) comes to the "Doctor" (a person playing a role), it is important to know that a "policy" of her dad Bob (a person) will be paying the bill.  Hence the reason a Person is mapped in a different table.

PolicyType defines what type of policy a policy really is. In your case, you may have 18 different policy types, like ExistingOriginalMediCare, AgeInOriginalMediCare and so forth. This is where you can store data that influences the "rules" of your policy.  For example, some types of policies are only available to people living in California. One system I worked on had thousands of policy types each with hundreds of properties that applications used to infer business rules. This allowed business to create new policy types and "rules" without recompiling the system and everything that depended on it.

However, one can simplify it by taking out the inheritance while maintaining the same capabilities. Here we assume that there will be no other "role" than "patient" and no other "party" than a "person".

[image: Simplified Model]

That said, it really depends on whether the data will be reused by other applications and how temporal data and associations really are. Feel free to adapt. I often reference these books when designing systems:

1. [Enterprise Patterns and MDA: Building Better Software with Archetype Patterns and UML](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/uml/032111230x)
2. [Enterprise Model Patterns: Describing the World (UML Version)](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/uml/9781935504054)
3. [The Data Model Resource Book, Volume 3: Universal Patterns for Data Modeling](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/9780470178454)

They have fundamentally changed the way I look at "data".

Comment: Thanks for the long answer.  I know that this took lots of thought and time.  In this situation, customer is not actually a patient.  Customer is a B2B partner that we're tracking policies on.  In other words, providers have medicare policies and we want to know what those are.  I'll look into this a bit further.  The database is SQL server.

Comment: Then its best to rename "Patient" to "Partner" and "Person" to "Organization".  The pattern remains the same. Do you have to keep track of who the beneficiaries are on the policies?

Comment: no beneficiaries/patients involved.  Purely B2B.  I had to hack together this question to protect some stuff which is the cause for confusion...

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at TPT (Table Per Type) for this, take a look here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/22/table-per-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx

This would mean that you could have a table for each of these different concepts which extend a base table. The bonus of doing it this way is that later on you can add additional info to a specific type.

EG, customer would be your root table and then be extended with concepts such as OriginalMedicareCustomer

Comment: Depending on your model, TPT may be a challenge when it comes to foreign keys and cascading deletes.

Comment: Yeah its definitively a harder thing to do than a regular table structure but it has become a lot easier in the latest versions of EF

Answer (score 1):

If you want to normalize it, I recommend going about it like so:

```
public class Customer {
  // id, name, owner, etc
  public virtual IList<CustomerPolicy> Policies { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerPolicy {
  // id, name, etc
  public bool ExistingPatient { get; set; }
  public bool AgeInPatient { get; set; }
  public bool NewPatient { get; set; }
}
```

Without knowing more about your application, I can't say, but I'm guessing that the three booleans for each policy are mutually exclusive?  If so, I would instead do something like this:

```
public enum PatientType { Existing, AgeIn, NewPatient };

public class CustomerPolicy {
  // id, name, etc
  public PatientType PatientType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about your data requirements, but I'd keep it simple and within a table or two, something like this...

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    // or implement it via enum like below for policy type
    public bool Existing { get; set; }
    public bool AgeIn { get; set; }
    public bool New{ get; set; }
    // no 'virtual' means it's 'required', with virtual could be 'null'
    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
}
public enum PolicyBits
{
    None = 0x00,
    ExistingOriginalMediCare = 0x01,
    // ...
    AgeInOriginalMediCare = 0x100,
    // ...
}
public class Policy
{
    public int PolicyID { get; set; }
    public int PolicyTypeValue { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public PolicyBits PolicyType
    {
        get { return (PolicyBits)PolicyTypeValue; }
        set { PolicyTypeValue = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

...enum would help you scale down on the number of 'bits' - but it's not officially supported yet, will be from the next version and so far only in experimental, VS 2011 and .NET 4.5 (as I recall).

but you can temporarily work around it with something like below.

As for the model of the tables - I'm not sure how you want to 'switch' in between existing, new or age-in users - or could you have both or all three at the same time etc. Since all are bits I'm thinking one field should be enough - and maybe put it into a separate table for separation mostly - i.e. so you could redefine that, add new things or introduce new records etc.